# How to wait for first rsync process to complete before running next command in shell/bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, screen, rsync

Below is the script I have. Basically I just want to copy files from the other server by calling out this script. Some files are large and what happens is that it will kill the first rsync command before it completes and proceed with the next. I tried to use screen command but I'm not sure how to code Ctrl+a d (to detach) in shell/bash.

```
HFDIR=/var/opt/ubkp/data/local/prework/hotfixes
RODIR=/var/opt/ubkp/data/local/prework/rollouts
THFDIR=$(ls -t /var/opt/ubkp/data/local | grep hotfix | head -1)
TRODIR=$(ls -t /var/opt/ubkp/data/local | grep rollout | grep -v check | head -1)
user=$(/usr/seos/bin/sewhoami)
if [ $user = "root" ]; then
echo "This script should not be run as the TRUE root user"
echo "Log in so that \"sewhoami\" does not display \"root\" and then execute this script."
exit
else
#list of ROs and HFs 
list=/tmp/list.txt
echo -n "Enter Password: "
read -s PWD
# first rsync command
/usr/bin/expect<<EOD
spawn rsync -a $user@server:$HFDIR/* /var/opt/ubkp/data/local/$THFDIR
expect "assword"
send "$PWD\r" 
wait $!
expect eof
EOD
# second rsync command
/usr/bin/expect<<EOD
spawn rsync -a $user@server:$RODIR/* /var/opt/ubkp/data/local/$TRODIR
expect "assword"
send "$PWD\r"
expect eof
EOD
fi
exit
```

Comment: `spawn` creates a new process. You can use `pidof` command to track execution status of background process

Comment: There is no background process, it terminates the rsync command and spawn the next command.

Comment: i don't understand your code but without spawn your script will wait for rsync is finished before processing next command??

Comment: Alecxs, it's within EOD/expect so it needs to be run with spawn. it won't recognize rysnc command without it.

Answer (score 1):

Your second rsync will be killed after 10 seconds as that is the default timeout for `expect eof`. You should add a `wait` after the send, to wait forever until the process ends.

Also, your should remove the `$!` in the `wait`. It is a shell variable, not an expect variable. Fortunately in this case `$!` is empty because you have not run any commands in the shell in the background with `&`.